# Differentiating the meaning of the -able suffix ('able to be' vs 'to be')

Tags: suffixes

The suffix -able has several meanings, one of them is:

- (forming adjectives) to be: *payable*

How does one differentiate this meaning from the other meanins of *-able*? For example, how does one know whether *payable* means *able to be paid* or *to be paid*?

By the way, I didn't find other examples for the "to be"-meaning except for *payable*. Could you provide other examples?

Comment: [Almost] all words have different nuances, and many have different senses. Why are those ending in -able significantly different? Familiarity and dictionaries help with different usages available; familiarity and context help decide which sense is intended in a given sentence. Sometimes, ambiguity is not resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Payable" *does* mean "able to be paid"— specifically, it [means](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/payable) "that may, can, or must be paid."

I'm assuming you're referring to the use of "payable" in "accounts payable." This [refers](http://Merrhttps://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accounts%20payable) to "the balance due to a creditor on a current account," or in other words, the amount that must be paid. Accounts (that are) payable are those that can (must) be paid.

Comment: So, 'accounts payable' is an ambiguous phrase, but it has definite meaning in accounting?

Comment: @Daniel perhaps it would be ambiguous in a world where it were not an accounting term, but it is not really ambiguous in modern English: it always refers to the accounting concept, as evidenced by that appearing as the dictionary definition of the phrase in a general dictionary (i.e., not an accounting-specific dictionary).

Comment: Thank you! Could you also provide another example of the "to be"-meaning (other than 'payable')?

Comment: @Daniel "accounts receivable" is a similar concept to "accounts payable," but from the other side of the creditor-debtor relationship. Again, though, I would not say these mean "to be" as such—I think both are closer to "able to be."

Comment: Both 'payable' and 'receivable' come from accounting. I'm wondering if the 'to be'-meaning of the '-able' suffix is much rarer than 'able to be'-meaning?

Answer (score 0):

> How does one differentiate this meaning from the other meanings of -able? For example, how does one know whether payable means able to be paid or to be paid?

The solution is simple: you look at the context. **The importance of context cannot be overstated.** In English, (and probably a lot of other languages,) words without context may have several meanings: e.g. "Bank" - a place to deposit money, or the side of a river - how do we know the difference?

Comment: Identical orthographic representations may be different words.Your _bank_'s are homographs, different words, not merely different senses of a single word.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth but, of course, you only know that because of context... "Although of modest stock, his bearing was distinguished."  "The regime persecuted those with brown eyes and unfortunately, Farnsworth was distinguished."

Comment: I'm saying that 'In English, (and probably a lot of other languages,) words without context may have several meanings: e.g. "Bank" - a place to deposit money, or the side of a river ' implies wrongly that these are polysemes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not sure that it does or, if it does, that it particularly matters.

Comment: The difference between polysemes and homonyms doesn't matter on a site dedicated to linguists?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - it may or may not - **the context** will decide. For example, if we are speaking of the spelling of "bank" - it does not even matter if it is a noun or a verb.

Comment: I'm talking about the clarity of explanation, not whether a significant difference in meaning in a single example is made. You may mislead readers.

Comment: @ Interesting: are you suggesting some other guidance other than context?

Comment: After '[W]ords without context may have several meanings: eg ...' one would expect an example of a single word with two or more meanings to illustrate. You give two different (identical-looking and sounding) words.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm sorry, but you have lost me with *two different (identical-looking and sounding) words* - The point and focus is **context** - the nature of the example is irrelevant. The OP asks *For example, how does one know whether payable means able to be paid or to be paid?* The answer is **by context**. The example given, "bank", is a word from an elementary vocabulary and the OP will know the two meanings. The OP is looking for a "rule" but there are no "rules" and essentially, there is no other answer

Comment: That does not give us an excuse for sloppiness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118104/discussion-between-greybeard-and-edwin-ashworth).